# How to access the depth value of the neighbor pixels in WebGL?

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, shader

I want to make a toon border effect. For it, I'll use the depth value of the neighbor pixels of each pixel to determine if it is or isn't supposed to be blacked. How can I access that information inside the fragment shader?

Comment: Might want to accept the answer...

Comment: You could also use the standard derivatives extension and use fwidth or [dFdx](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/dFdx.xhtml). It only allows you to access the difference of some value and the value in the other fragment. What makes it totally useless is that it can only access neighboring pixels in the same triangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you render your scene in a normal way (vertex shader, then fragment shader - single pass) then in the fragment shader there is no way to access depth values for another pixels.

But:
You can **render scene twice** and perform some postprocessing effects. In the first run you store depth values and others (like normals, etc) in RenderTarget (in texture) then you use those textures **in the second pass**.

Here you have effect from XNA, but can be quickly ported to GLSL: http://xnameetingpoint.weebly.com/shader7f31.html

Here some link about Render to Texture: http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=1786

Hint: depth values will not be enough for border detection, you have **to use normals** as well. But it is covered in the above tutorial from XNA.